# webpack 2 ts-loader exclude node_modules not working

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I try to use `typescript 2.2.2` and `babel` loaders in `webpack 2` and exclude `node_modules`, but when try `webpack` command still get errors from `angular 4.0.0` which is in node_modules.

webpack.congfig.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var PROD = true;

    module.exports = {
        entry: path.join(__dirname, 'ng2', 'src','index.js'),
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ng2', 'dist'),
            filename: 'vendorNG2.js'
        },
        devtool: 'eval',
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        watch: true,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: [/node_modules/],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/],
                    use: {

                        loader: "babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true",
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015']
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: PROD ? [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                 compress: { warnings: false }
            })
      ] : []
    }
```

after webpack --progress command:

```
...
ERROR in /home/user/Projects/project/front/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(13,17): error TS2693: 'Map' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in /home/user/Projects/project/front/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(14,17): error TS2693: 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in ./ng2/src/app/main.ts
(19,14): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

You can see errors come from node_modules.

tsconfig.json v1:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json v2:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./ng2/dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "type":[],
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

v2 errors:

```
ERROR in /home/user/Projects/project/front/admin/tsconfig.json
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'type'.
 @ ./ng2/src/index.js 8:0-21

ERROR in ./ng2/src/app/main.ts
Module build failed: error while parsing tsconfig.json
 @ ./ng2/src/index.js 8:0-21
```

tsconfig.js v3 add ("experimentalDecorators": true) some errors gone:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./ng2/dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

v3 errors :

...
ERROR in /home/user/Projects/project/front/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(13,17): error TS2693: 'Map' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in /home/user/Projects/project/front/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts
    (14,17): error TS2693: 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: Whats your `tsconfig` look like?

Comment: look updated post

Comment: Have you tried adding `experimentalDecorators: true` to your `tsconfig` ? -   If they doesn't work, try adding `"types": []`

Comment: Try `"types:[]"` - not `"type"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added exclude node_modules to your tsconfig?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Also, you aren't specifying which versions of Typescript and Angular you are using.

Edit:
You updated your question to specify that you're using Angular 4 but your updated errors show a node_modules/angular2/ folder which doesn't seem right. Before going further, try deleting your node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Otherwise it looks like you're having a typings issue.  Do you have any @types installed?

Here is an example of how my tsconfig.json is setup:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "types": [ "jasmine", "lodash", "core-js" ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot",
        "temp"
    ]
}
```

My node_modules folder is in the parent directory, so I specify that in the typeRoots.
With that I also have the following types installed as well:

```
"@types/core-js": "0.9.37",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.43",
"@types/lodash": "4.14.55",
```

Comment: Updated answer after seeing that the question was updated